# my form failed to be submitted

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which works by itself but when I try it on wordpress, it shows the login but when I click on submit, it does not submit the form, and goes to following address and shows a white page.

```
    http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php


    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
              Username <input type="text" name="username"  />
              <br /> 
              Password <input type="password" name="password" />
              <br />
             <input type="submit" value="Login" />

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST["username"])
        ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perhaps go into more detail of what you are trying to achieve.

Any reason you are not using [wp_login_form()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)?

As for the white screen, I would also recommend to turn on debugging, inside your wp-config.php file is the line `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` . Change that to true.  ( I can only also assume the login showed a white screen because of missing nonce fields, which would go away with using wp_login_form() )

Comment: actually when I get the credentials, will send them to a webservice to authorize users, but the problem is that when they are authorized I cant redirect them to the new page to use the plugin.

Comment: would you please have a look at this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873303/how-to-go-to-other-pages-of-my-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute in the form field

```
<form method="post" name="form_name" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```